# How to Insert HTML comment tag after </html> with JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I dont know whether it is possible looking for advice

if anyone have used wp-rocket they would know when page is served from cache it shows comment tag after  that page is generated at hh/mm/ss

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Site Title </title>
    </head>
    <body>
Body area
    </body>
    </html>

<!-- Like this -->
```

[Same as in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyFYa.png)

Comment: why? it does not like anyone would see it, or are you talking about server-side js?

Comment: there is a method document.createComment(); but may i know the purpose of injecting comments after the closing tag?

Comment: for showing when i updated my page last time

Comment: Shouldn't you do that on the backend (if at all) instead of in the browser?

Comment: You are mistaken if you think that using javascript within the page will modify the file itself stored on server. Why can't you just do it manually?

Comment: I think i saw somewhere it is bookmarked that we can update using a js onload it will modify the html

Comment: @str i am newbie dont know that much so just doing a shortcut

Comment: Only for the life of the page in browser. Each time you load the page it pulls the original file from the server. There is nothing you can do with javascript in the page to actually modify the file on the server. That would require being done by server side programming language

Comment: @charlietfl i knew it, but i think it serves my need for now

Comment: @charlietfl you closed it saying duplicate but all those questions are talking about inner html not outer

Comment: @Asad That is not true. For example the last question is clearly about an element (e.g. a comment node) *after* another element.

Comment: @str i saw them when posting, none of them serves my need, they are not working outside </html> - fine for inside

Comment: @Asad Yes it *does* work outside of the `html` element.

Comment: @str please check the answer by @ Solanki below which serves my need

Comment: @str i tried those but they didnt worked for me i posted it afterwards

Answer (score 1):

***Working Code!!*** using jQuery `after()` method.

Observe the result after **Inspect** in *Browser Developer Tools (F12)*

```js
$('html').after('<!-- Like this -->');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Site Title </title>
</head>

<body>
  Body area
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow! Amazing never crossed my mind

Comment: Nice! it works!

Comment: Is there a way to put line break with this?

like

</html>
Break
break
<!-- Like this -->
Break
break

Comment: @Asad: For adding any break, we need insert <br> tag, which can't be added after </html> ending tag. If user tries to do so, it thows console / functional error. Thanks!

Comment: @solanki is it possible to replace </html> itself with 2 linebreaks ? like done with div inner html

Comment: @Asad: Let me check this

Comment: @Asad :  Please, see the updated answer and do inspect. it will add 3 <br> (break line) before </html> ending tag

Comment: @solanki... That is a bad idea as you are making the whole HTML invalid. Asad probably meant `\n`, not `<br>`. But this whole question is odd anyway.

Comment: @solanki i think there is no way to put breaks after </html> not before, above i just gave an example so as you said earlier i think not possible

Comment: @Asad  yes, i think so, both are right, basically for better way we can insert break tag before </body> ending tag.

Comment: @solanki good enough, something is better than nothing, serves my need for now, i only wanted to put breaks so as to make it look good